# How to Use RelayCommand and IList to Read XML and Display Results in .NET MAUI Picker

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I would like to state upfront here that if I seem to be using app, App1, or other generic names they reference the same app.
I am trying to use a RelayCommand to read a XML document, and post the results on the GUI. I am using .NET MAUI, and MVVM community library.

This is my dropdown XAML file [DropDownButton.xaml]:

```
<Frame xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.CustomControls.DropDownButton"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ModelViewModel">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,.2*">
        <Picker
            x:DataType="viewmodel:ModelViewModel"
            Title="Product"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayModelCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

I also have the relay command at hand here:
[ModelViewModel.cs] - File Name

```
public partial class ModelViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ModelViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<string> items;

        [RelayCommand]
        void DisplayModel()
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("info.xml",FileMode.Open));
            XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);

            XmlNode prodsNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("product")[0];
            DataReader a1 = new DataReader();
            Prod[] products = a1.LoadProds(prodsNode);
            foreach( Prod product in products )
            {
                Items.Add(product.ToString());
            }
            

        }
```

I do not understand why it is not working. My thoughts are coming from the error mentioning something about an IList which I believe it is looking for a List and not an ObservableCollection.

I am trying to read an XML document and develop a picker for a selection of sorts.

#Update
I changed the binding to the following and it still did not produce any text in the GUI.
[DropDownButton.xaml]

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,.2*">
        <Picker
            x:DataType="viewmodel:ModelViewModel"
            Title="Product"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Grid>
```

#Update 2
I updated the DropDownButton.cs with the following additions:

```
using app.ViewModel;

namespace app.CustomControls;

public partial class DropDownButton : Frame
{
    public DropDownButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DropDownButton(ModelViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

I had an error that Items didn't exist and then that the DropDownButton constructor was missing a no-argument constructor I managed to make the errors disappear but I do not see the products on the dropdown.

This is the ModelViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
 public partial class ModelViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ModelViewModel()
        {
            Laptops = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<string> laptops;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string book;

        [RelayCommand]
        void DisplayModel()
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("info.xml",FileMode.Open));
            XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            xmlDoc.Load(book);

            XmlNode productNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("products")[0];
            DataReader a1 = new DataReader();
            Prod[] prods = a1.LoadModels(prodsNode);
            foreach( Prod prod in prods )
            {
                book = prod.ToString();
                Laptops.Add(book);
            }
            

        }
```

Everytime I do the following:

```
 public ModelViewModel()
        {
            DisplayModel();
            Laptops = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
```

It marks that Laptops does not exist in this context error. I don't know if this is the proper way to call the method.

I have updated the code to as follows:

```
 public partial class ModelViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<string> laptops;
        public ModelViewModel()
        {
            Laptops = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            DisplayModel();
        }

       

        [ObservableProperty]
        Model book;

        [RelayCommand]
        void DisplayModel()
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("data.xml",FileMode.Open));
            XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);

            XmlNode modelsNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Models")[0];
            DataReader a1 = new DataReader();
            Model[] models = a1.LoadModels(prodsNode);
            foreach( Model model in models )
            {
                Laptops.Add(string.Format("{0}",prod.name));
            }
            

        }
```

I happen to following this tutorial and it seems that Laptops is not existing the way I am coding it is there a better way [MAUI .NET Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/dotnet-maui-for-beginners/dotnet-maui-data-binding-with-mvvm-xaml-5-of-8-dotnet-maui-for-beginners) or maybe my implementation is just wrong.

#Update
The latest error that I am getting from Build Only is that the string is in the incorrect format. I looked up online and tried doing:

```
string.Format("{0}",prod.name)
```

It also happens that `prod.name` is a string already. There is also not an error code in the terminal.

Comment: `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable` in your VM that you want to the data from.  It is NOT a `Command`.  You probably want to bind `ItemsSource` to `Items`, and then execute the code to read the XML file in the constructor

Comment: you updated your XAML, did you also update your VM to load the data?

Comment: @Jason I apologize for taking long I was just editing and dealing with new errors that appeared I put them in my post.

Comment: You posted the code behind, not the VM

Comment: @Jason What file would be that one the xaml.cs file?

Comment: No, you already posted that.  I am asking - repeatedly - if you have modified `ModelViewModel` so that it loads the data

Comment: I just uploaded that file.

Comment: your code to load the data is in `DisplayModel` which is **never called**.  How do you expect the data to get loaded?  Please see the suggestion in my **first comment**

Comment: Every time I do the following: ```
 public ModelViewModel()
        {
            DisplayModel();
            Laptops = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
``` It says laptops does not exist in the current context.

Comment: 1) *"I do not see the products on the dropdown."* - because `public DropDownButton()` doesn't set BindingContext. After InitializeComponent, add line `BindingContext = new ModelViewModel();`. 2) Is your xaml now `ItemsSource="{Binding Laptops}"`?

Comment: 3) *"Laptops does not exist in this context"* - is that the only error you have now? If so, see if you can run anyway (maybe Intellisense is just confused).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I put in my latest update the error that occurs it says that the string is in an incorrect format. It also raises an unhandled exception.

Comment: Your observable collection property is `laptops` not `Laptops`.

Comment: `Laptops.Add(string.Format("{0}",prod.name));` should be `Laptops.Add(string.Format("{0}",model.name));`

Comment: @ChrisBD: clarification: the *field* is named `laptops`. The generated *ObservableProperty* is named `Laptops`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - not in the code posted. `[ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<string> laptops;` There is no `Laptops` property shown. Admittedly not all of the class has been posted, so perhaps its missing.

Comment: `Laptops` is the observable property ***generated*** from `laptops` See [ObservableProperty attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty). `laptops` is not a `property`; it lacks `get` and `set`.